# Time to expire a token in GAM for SD

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd, genexus-gam

I'm using GAM to create the authentication system for my SD app, I wish the user to login once and never again (unless the user logout).

I checked [my security policies](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Security+Session+Management+in+Applications+using+GAM,) and the field "Token expires (minutes)" is 0.

This mean the user session will last "forever"? If not, how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you can check this link to see the meaning of the property:
http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?18577

Answer (score -1):

If it does not work(it may not) , try using clientstorageapi to save user id.

Here you will find info about how to use this mobile api:

http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?ClientStorage+API

Good look.